# How compare an Excel file with a web page using Katalon Studio?

Tags: excel, groovy, katalon-studio

Hey guys i am working with Katalon Studio as an automation tool.

My problem is that i want to compare a table in a web page with an excel file.
The table is generated after applying several filters (select multiple options from the web page and then click on see products).

And all of this process should be automatic, the code must choose the filters and display the products in a table and then compare it with an excel file to see how accurate it is.

Comment: Hi Omar. What have you tried so far? This is not the place to ask someone to do everything for you. People can help with a particular problem, but they need to see you at least tried to do something.

Comment: Hi,
I have done some research but i coudn't find something that might help. I am not looking for a "Ready-To-Use" solution i am just looking for the right path to find a solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Apache POI` (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/4.1.0) to interact with `XLS` files.

You can download `JAR` file and simply add to your project: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/import_java_library.html#using-katalon-project-settings

Comment: Thank you this would help a lot.

Comment: @OmarTajine : If it solved problem, please mark as solution. Thanks!